# Ceteris Paribus interpretation if it isn't possible in reality

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients

Does it make sense to include both respondent's age (in years) and respondent's partner's age (in years) in a simple linear regression with cross-sectional data? The outcome variable, for example, could be life satisfaction and I would be interested in the effect of respondents' and their partners' age on life satisfaction. I am wondering how to interpret the coefficients then having the ceteris paribus interpretaion in mind... How could age of respondent increase while I hold partner's age constant? In reality, if age of respondent increases by one year, also partner's age increases by one year. Thus, i cannot hold  partner's age constant while increasing respondent's age, right? The idea applies to different variables. So, does it make sense to include two variables in a regression which are perfectly multicollinear in reality but not in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the phrase "holding age constant". What it means for the example you quote is that we look at the effect of partner's age having already taken account of any influence of respondent's age. You can think of it as having first built a model with just respondent's age, calculating the residuals from that model, seeing how partner's age predicts the variation left over in the residual.

In your example if the ages are correlated I might be inclined to use two new variables: average age of the couple, and difference in couple's ages. But this would depend on the scientific question being asked.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to understand the concept of ceteris paribus better!